# visit from 192.168.6.145 on my private 192.168.1.255 network?

Tags: networking, ip, home-networking

I have noticed a visit from 192.168.6.145 ip address to my website hosted on my local host 192.168.1.5. My router NetGear (gateway) has ip 192.168.1.1.

how is this possible? does it mean that someone was between my NetGear and modem? this indicates another network behind my modem, right?

In fact I am interested in following: is this possible that connection from ip 192.168.6.145 was initiated from outside of my LAN (so it might be someone from WAN who has been given such ip?)

Comment: 192.168.xxx.xxx is non-routable which means that your router should  not allow anything from outside to come in as that address, nor should it send anything out like that. The device on 192.168.6.145 is almost certainly inside your LAN. It could another computer or phone/ipad/mobile device in your house or if your router isn't locked down properly, perhaps a neighbour connecting to your wireless router.

Comment: please put it as an answer, I'll accept it. The clarification of "almost certainly" would be appreciated since this scrap of uncertainty is the source of my anxiety.

Comment: 1. What is your Netgear's LAN subnet mask? 2. See if your Netgear has a list of connected devices. If 192.168.6.145 shows up with a name or MAC address, you may be able to guess what device it might be.

Comment: Netgar has IP 192.168.1.1 on LAN and is set to get IP dynamically from ISP. also if there was a device connected to NetGear it would have IP 192.168.1.X as all my machines, right? And at the moment I don't see that strange device of course

Comment: What is the exact model of your Netgear router? In your router's settings pages, there's usually a place where you could change the LAN IP address (currently set to 192.168.1.1). Right under that will be the LAN subnet mask. Both the IP address and the subnet mask together determine the form of addresses allowed on a particular network. (If your Netgear's LAN subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, then the devices on the LAN can have addresses of the form 192.168.1.x. If the LAN subnet mask is 255.255.0.0, then the devices on that LAN can have addresses of the form 192.168.x.x.)

Comment: Maybe you (or rather the web server) got fooled by a `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your website in your local network (like using xamp , Apache and etc on your computer) its possible to who on your Local Area Network (LAN), visits the site and you'll notice an IP Address on your LAN visited the website (IP Like: 192.168.xxx.yyy). (This User is on the Server Side, but you run your host on your local server, you'll see these IP from who visited the site that connected to your router)

But if you running your website on a web-based Host that is on a server, it wont possible to see a IP like above that visited the site from your LAN, so who visits your website that connected via your router, you wont see your Local IP (and you'll see your Internet IP). But if you see some IP like that (also called LAN's IP), i says a user that were connected to your server, visited the site (This user is on the Server Side).

Comment: as I said, site is hosted on my local machine, I am using glassfish. I know that I will see IP, but like 192.168.1.XXX. This actual ip however is 192.168.6.XXX. ??????????

Comment: Yes, Its Possible. its a range of your LAN IP Address (Private IP). You may using Wireless routers ?!

Comment: yes, I have also wireless TP-Link, but it is connected via NetGear. Every connection to host hosting website from wireless device goes through TP-Link to NetGear-> to glassfish and has been always logged as 192.168.1.2 (TP-Link IP)